# Setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES just has no effect even though I put it before pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda

I have tried many methods to set cuda device as 1, or 0,1 however,most of them didn't work, I followed some solution but not work...

```
# '''cmd:CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1, python mytest.py'''   #stil shows 0

import os 
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1' #cannot work

#export 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'='1' #how to use this in detail?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    import torch
    print(torch.cuda.current_device()) #show 0, os.environ method cannot works

    torch.cuda.set_device(0)
    print(torch.cuda.current_device()) #show 0, it can works

    torch.cuda.set_device(1)
    print(torch.cuda.current_device()) #show 1, it can works

    torch.cuda.set_device('cuda:0')
    print(torch.cuda.current_device()) #show 0, it can works

    torch.cuda.set_device('cuda:1')
    print(torch.cuda.current_device()) #show 1, it can works
    
    torch.cuda.set_device('cuda:0,1') #Error: why it shows Invalid device string: 'cuda:0,1'
    print(torch.cuda.current_device())

    device = torch.device("cuda:1") 
    print(torch.cuda.current_device()) #show 0, it cannot works
```

The only method that can work is `torch.cuda.set_device()`, however when I want to use 2 gpus, like set_device('cuda:0,1') it still shows error, because it cannot accept multiple devices? If so how can I set multi devices?

P.S my environment is a Linux server, by nvidia-smi,it shows,

```
 CUDA Version: 10.2  

| GPU  Name   Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
|==============+===============+============|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   68C    P0    62W /  70W |  0MiB / 15109MiB |26% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    16W /  70W |   0MiB / 15109MiB | 6% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: `CUDA_VISIBlE_DEVICES`???

Comment: @talonmies sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Read your code carefully. You have a typo

Comment: You have a lower-case `l` where you are supposed to have an uppercase `L`

Comment: @talonmies Thanks lot, I have corrected this typo, however, it still cannot work

Comment: try: `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"`  1. You must do this after importing `os`.  2. You must do this before doing anything that touches CUDA, such as `import torch`.  3.  Note that after doing this, from the perspective of torch, **it still thinks it is using device 0**, because this *remaps* CUDA device IDs.  However if you watch torch and also watch `nvidia-smi` at the same time, you will see that although torch thinks it is using device 0, `nvidia-smi` shows it using a different device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all scripts about device in code and try:

> CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python test.py

It would auto remap device IDs.

If not work, maybe you implement the distributed data parallel in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Place the **os.environ[...]** imports BEFORE you import **torch**.

The file [pytorch/torch/_prims/utils.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/be10787988dcc93fdfe314f19020e09c31b780fd/torch/_prims/utils.py#L13) calls:

```
 if torch.cuda.is_available():
```

which makes all os.environ calls inefficient. See this [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/80876).